# Java get X, Y, Width, Height cords from an Image in Slick2D

Tags: java, variables, slick2d

I'm making a game(side scrolling) and I need to know the cords of x, y, height, width of an Image. The Image name is "apple". I have tried apple.x and apple.height etcetera. I donno maybe I can turn the image in to an rectangle or something to get the cords. I have no idea.

Here is my Code:

```
    public class Play extends BasicGameState{
       Image apple;

    public void init(...){
       apple = new Image("res/Apple.png");
    }

    public void render(...){
       g.drawImage(apple, 200 + playerPosX, 200 + playerPosY);
       }
    }
```

Comment: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html use the getters

Answer (score 0):

see: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html

You can use the getter methods:

```
int width = apple.getWidth();
int height = apple.getHeight();
```

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by getting the X/Y.
You define the x & y in the drawing method, that means you know the X/Y already.
But you can check the documentation maybe the things like:

```
apple.TOP_LEFT
apple.TOP_RIGHT
```

Hope this helps.